# Echo to all bot

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

У меня есть echo bot на телеграм.

Его код:

```
import config
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def repeat_all_messages(message): # Название функции не играет никакой роли
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     bot.infinity_polling()
```

Хотелось бы узнать, как сделать, чтобы все сообщения отправлялись всем пользователям. Этакий "анонимный глобальный чат"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо запомнить `chat.id` всех пользователей, которые начинали чат с вашим ботом. Для этого в момент, когда пользователь начинает чат, сохраняем в свою БД. Если хранить данные в оперативной памяти, то они потеряются при первом же падении бота.

В момент, когда нужно разослать сообщение всем пользователям - достаём все `chat.id` из базы данных и в цикле пробегаясь по ним отправляем:

```
for chat_id in chats_list:
  bot.send_message(chat_id, message.text)
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Yukich06, Пожалуйста! Рад помочь. Можете ещё плюсик поставить к ответу)